# How to check heap memory usage and tomcat version in one command with check_jmx4perl and nagios

Tags: java, tomcat, nagios, jolokia, server-monitoring

We are using Jolokia and jmx4perl to monitor tomcat instances with Nagios. We are currently using the following command definition:

```
define command {
 command_name         check_tomcat
 command_line         $USER3$/check_jmx4perl \
                          --url $ARG1$ \
                          --mbean java.lang:type=Memory \
                          --attribute HeapMemoryUsage \
                          --path used \
                          --base java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage/max \
                          --label "Heap-Memory: %.2r% used (%.2v %u / %.2b %w)" \
                          --warning 80 --critical 90
}
```

... which gives us a nice output like this in Nagios:

```
OK - Heap-Memory: 37.93% used (295520640 / 779091968)
```

In an ideal world, I would also like to get the Tomcat version like so:

```
OK - Tomcat 7.0.68 - Heap-Memory: 37.93% used (295520640 / 779091968)
```

Can this be done with one command or will I need 2 command definitions and 2 service definitions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First yes can check tomcat with your custom configration.That configration will have your command and service for checking tomcat.Then you can read that cfg file like this.

```
--config /etc/nagios/check_jmx4perl/tomcat.cfg
                --server servername \
                --check tc_servlet_requests \
                --critical 1000 \
                servletname
```

To write command and service in a single configuration file.Just write your command definition followed by service definition of that command.Also make sure the .cfg file has root privileges.

Jmx4Perl provides an alternate way for accessing Java JEE Server
  management interfaces which are based on JMX (Java Management
  Extensions). It is an agent based approach, where a small Java
  Webapplication deployed on the application server provides an
  HTTP/JSON based access to JMX MBeans registered within the
  application server.

HOW IT WORKS

For the agent mode a small Java Agent WAR (web archive) needs to be
  deployed on the Java application server. This agent is provided by
  the Jolokia project (www.jolokia.org). There is no need to add any
  startup parameters to the application server and to open any
  additional ports.The Perl module JMX::Jmx4Perl accesses the deployed agent servlet
  and transform the request's results from JSON into a simple Perl
  object.

Comment: I think I have a general understanding of what you are saying but I am missing a couple of things. Would you be able to provide a bit more details as to what goes into /etc/nagios/check_jmx4perl/tomcat.cfg and how you would then define the command that checks both the server name and its status?